# What is the recommended database schema for overlapping rules (such as price changes)?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Envision the rules that govern the price of a hotel room.

> 1. In general, $100 a night
> 2. On Fridays or Saturdays, $120
> 3. In the summer months, $150
> 4. For a special next week, $80
> 5. Etc..

Given a database of hotel rooms with varying rules like this, how would you model this in the database so that you can quickly and easily modify and query the price at a given time?

Comment: and don't forget you'll need some sort of priority, like "if it's a friday AND a summer month AND a special week, then what is the price"? not trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an order of priority. Then you store each rule with its priority and its criteria (from - to + weekdays bitmap for instance), and you find the matching rule with the highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's multiple ways you could do that, but the one that I'm most familiar with is to store attributes 'date-from' and 'date-to' in the table along with the corresponding price for that duration. Then, while querying you could specify sysdate(or any other desired date) in the where clause to retrieve the correct price.

Alternatively, if you had the same rules for all rooms in the hotel, you could create a separate table with the rules(date-from, date-to, price(or %change in price)). This would be a more normalized way of doing it, but that would mean you have the same rules for all rooms.

It all depends on what the business rules are, really.

Comment: I was thinking of a similar setup, but I'm imagining the overlapping rules of "$150 on Saturdays forever" with "special of $80 for the next week".  Intuitively you want $80 when querying that timeframe but there becomes ambiguity of precedence

Comment: @Jim, the system cannot guess the precedence, so you have to include it in the rules and whoever sets the prices must explicitly define it. The only other alternative is to have automatic precedences à la CSS (based on how "specific" a rule is), but we all know this is not always as intuitive as one might think.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, you would additionally have to store a priority flag of sorts to indicate the precedence. Then while querying, pick the one with the minimum(or maximum) priority.